# Plotly rebase graph after Range selector

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-python

I would like to know if it's possible to have a rebased series after a range selector in plotly.
I mean I have a code like this :

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')

df['AAPL.High'] = 100*df['AAPL.High']/df["AAPL.High"].iloc[0]
fig = px.line(df, x='Date', y='AAPL.High', title='Time Series with Range Slider and Selectors')

fig.update_xaxes(
    rangeselector=dict(
        buttons=list([
            dict(count=1, label="1m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=6, label="6m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=1, label="YTD", step="year", stepmode="todate"),
            dict(count=1, label="1y", step="year", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(step="all")
        ])
    )
)
fig.show()
```

Is it possible to rebase the data after each click on button ?

I tried to rebase the series each time I change the button selector with plotly.